# Is there any privacy issue using a Microsoft professional account in a personal computer?

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts, microsoft-account

If I add my Microsoft Professional account to my personal computer, could my company access to it, manage it or monitor its activity by any way?

I want to add it to use Microsoft Teams and access my email in this computer too but I don't want to give them any control over it.

I'm using Windows 10

Comment: There isn't really any control that they get. Its more monitoring and possibly remotely deactivate a license, but only to that account. So they could remotely tell your email client that it should sign out, but there is little control such account gives.  If your computer is domain joined, your IT company has much more control over it.

Comment: @LPChip Thank you. What kind of monitoring could they have? Activity? Installed software? Browser history? Or it's just related with the apps which which use that account? It isn't domain joined.

Comment: Its really just related to the Office product itself. They probably can see your computername, that you have one license in use with the company email address and possibly a time/date of last succesful login. But even if you were to not do this, they can see when you are online in Teams, so they can already see that anyway.